# Customizing GeoRSS icon in ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, icon, georss

I have this piece of script to customize the icon of some GeoRSS points, but I have no display and no error in the console.

```
  var map;
    require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", 
            "esri/layers/GeoRSSLayer", "esri/InfoTemplate", "dojo/parser",
            "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/dom-style", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
            "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",
            "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
            "dojo/_base/Color","dojo/domReady!"],
    function(Map, Tiled, 
            GeoRSSLayer, InfoTemplate,
            parser, arrayUtils, PictureMarkerSymbol,
            SimpleRenderer, Color,  domStyle ) {
        
        map = new Map("map");
        var carte = new Tiled("http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer");
        map.addLayer(carte);
        var georss = new GeoRSSLayer("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2654618/data-mixed.xml");
           georss.on("load", function() {
                    domStyle.set("loading", "display", "none");
        // create an info template
                    var template = new InfoTemplate("${name}", "${description}");
  // set the info template for the feature layers that make up the GeoRSS layer
  // the GeoRSS layer contains one feature layer for each geometry type
                    var layers = georss.getFeatureLayers();
                    var picRenderer = new PictureMarkerSymbol("http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/YellowCircleLargeB.png", 16, 16);
                    var georssRenderer = new SimpleRenderer(picRenderer); 
                    arrayUtils.forEach(layers, function(l) {
                    l.setInfoTemplate(template);
                    l.setRenderer(georssRenderer)
});
});
                    map.addLayer(georss);
                                        //THE END                      
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your module IDs in your require dependency list do not match the aliases in the callback provided to require(). Things get out of whack after dojo/parser...

Here's a working example with a corrected require:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, IE=9, IE=10">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//js.arcgis.com/3.7/js/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; 
      }
    </style>

    <script src="//js.arcgis.com/3.7/"></script>
    <script>
var map;
require([
    "esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
    "esri/layers/GeoRSSLayer", "esri/InfoTemplate", "dojo/parser",
    "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/dom-style", "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol", 
    "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer", "dojo/_base/Color",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function (
    Map, Tiled,
    GeoRSSLayer, InfoTemplate, parser, 
    arrayUtils, domStyle, PictureMarkerSymbol,
    SimpleRenderer, Color
) {
    map = new Map("map");
    var carte = new Tiled("http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer");
    map.addLayer(carte);
    var georss = new GeoRSSLayer("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2654618/data-mixed.xml");
    georss.on("load", function () {
        // domStyle.set("loading", "display", "none");
        // create an info template
        var template = new InfoTemplate("${name}", "${description}");
        // set the info template for the feature layers that make up the GeoRSS layer
        // the GeoRSS layer contains one feature layer for each geometry type
        var layers = georss.getFeatureLayers();
        console.log("layers...because I'm curious", layers);
        var picRenderer = new PictureMarkerSymbol("http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/YellowCircleLargeB.png", 16, 16);
        var georssRenderer = new SimpleRenderer(picRenderer);
        arrayUtils.forEach(layers, function (l) {
            l.setInfoTemplate(template);
            l.setRenderer(georssRenderer)
       });
    });
    map.addLayer(georss);
    //THE END                      
});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

On jsbin:  http://jsbin.com/OzIqegI/1/

Alternatively, if you only need to change the symbol used for points from a georss file, look at the pointSymbol constructor option:

```
var georss = new GeoRSSLayer("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2654618/data-mixed.xml", {
  pointSymbol: new PictureMarkerSymbol("http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/YellowCircleLargeB.png", 16, 16)
});
map.addLayer(georss);
```