# What free or open source cloud-based software is recommended by/for the GIS community?

Tags: open-source-gis, web-service, free-software, cloud-gis

*Note: This question is intended to complement an [earlier question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/12105/753) on installed, desktop software.*

What GIS-related, or even non-GIS-specific, web- or cloud-based software/tools/services -- that are free -- do you find useful, whether for GIS development or application?

For example, I'm finding that **Google Docs** (aka, Google Drive) increasingly useful for general productivity and **Google Maps** is always useful as an street atlas or as a globe.

A specialized example is [**Q-Cogo**](http://q-cogo.com/), useful for coordinate geometry.

Comment: does fusion tables count? [technically not open-source but has an api] http://www.google.com/drive/apps.html#fusiontables

Comment: Suggest this be made community wiki since there will likely be many "correct" answers.

Comment: @Mapperz - I think it counts, since the question asks for free **OR** open source (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** Nowadays I prefer [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) for this, primarily because it allows you to create any number of files. This lets you create more realistically sized/organized demo apps, rather than stuffing everything into one HTML/JS/CSS file. Here's a nice Leaflet example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y9uk2G?p=info

I have found [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to be extremely useful in prototyping and demonstrating JavaScript/HTML/CSS pages, for everything from complex web maps to simple HTML forms.

JSBin example (from [another GIS.se question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/73996/753)): http://jsbin.com/OzIqegI/1/edit

[image: JSBin example]

I especially like JSBin because [the entire platform is open source](https://github.com/remy/jsbin/) and you can easily download it and [run it on your local machine](https://github.com/remy/jsbin/blob/master/docs/running-your-own-jsbin.md).

JSFiddle is nearly ubiquitous among web developers though -- a common response being "just make a JSFiddle" when someone asks for help with some web dev issue.

Answer (score 5):

http://geojson.io/
is the dopeness
geojson.io is a quick, simple tool for creating, viewing, and sharing maps. geojson.io is named after GeoJSON, an open source data format, and it supports GeoJSON in all ways - but also accepts KML, GPX, CSV, TopoJSON, and other formats.
[cartodb](http://cartodb.com/)
has a basic free account
CartoDB is a cloud based mapping, analysis and visualization engine that lets users build spatial applications for both mobile and the web
[TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/)
so freaking pretty
TileMill is the design studio you need to create stunning interactive maps.
[dat](http://dat-data.com/)
huzzah!
data version control

killer tools
[scraperwiki](https://scraperwiki.com/)
[okfn labs](http://okfnlabs.org/)

get geojson/topojson
[mapshaper](http://mapshaper.org/)
[geoconverter](http://geoconverter.hsr.ch/)
[my geodata converter](http://converter.mygeodata.eu/vector)
[KML to GeoJSON](http://mapbox.github.io/togeojson/)

maps service
[leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/)
[DON'T USE GOOGLE](http://petewarden.com/2013/09/09/why-you-should-stop-pirating-googles-geo-apis/)

and random repo
[mapbox's github](https://github.com/mapbox)
[odi's github](https://github.com/theodi)

Comment: Thanks. More description (and objectivity) would go a long way, though.

Comment: pretty descriptive imo...objectivity?

Answer (score 2):

[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/) allows you to add JavaScript/HTML/CSS in one place by simply signing up for GitHub which is free and has unlimited space (for now...).

To view your result, type in http://bl.ocks.org/[username]/[gist#] or get a browser extension which can use Leaflet, D3, jQuery, or anything. The site is run by [Mike Bostock](https://twitter.com/mbostock), creator of [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) and is used for showing code examples. If you just want to check out someone's Gists then you can simply put in their GitHub username.

Examples: [GL-Solar, Rainbow Road edition](http://bl.ocks.org/migurski/5130639) by Mike Migurski,
[Iceland Topography](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4687713) by Mike Bostock.

Answer (score 1):

[Color Brewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) is a great tool for chosing colors scales. 
[Map Projection Selection Tool](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~savricb/selectiontool/) is tool for chosing a correct map projection.

Answer (score 1):

While very limited in their presentation, Google Fusion tables have the advantage that they present a very familiar map interface if you have a broad, non-GIS user community. After all, everybody has used Google maps.

Answer (score 1):

I would also add the [geoman.io](https://geoman.io/geojson-editor) project. Once you select the "Editor" you can create your own Leaflet-based map using a lot of shapes available from the panel 9circles, polygons, lines, etc). The tool has also quite wide saving option with the following formats: GeoJson, TopoJson, WKT, SHP, CSV, KML and Shapefile.

It's very similar to [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0).

[image]